# Notifiy when Cassandra replica receives a write

Tags: cassandra, replication

I would like to measure the time it takes for a write made on one replica to propagate to other geo-distributed replicas (for experimental purposes). Does Cassandra provide some mechanism to measure this?

PS. A basic google search returned no straightforward results (in fact nothing relevant at all), hence I'm assuming doing this isn't easy. Any other suggestions involving other tools are also welcome.

Comment: Perhaps you can do that by logging some of Cassandra activity. You can do that with `logback.xml` in configuration directory.

Answer (score 2):

For just a one time thing, you can enable trace on a query and do a CL.ALL query, the trace data will have timestamps for it getting to each replica. But its something that you cant really do for all queries.

To get a more general sense you can use [CASSANDRA-11569](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11569) to get the cross DC message latency, which is how long the coordinators mutation takes to get to a replica (or at least other DC). This wont necessarily be indicative of how long it takes a quorum of nodes in that other DC to get mutation due to proxy writes.

Node's time drifting can really make it hard though.

Some people have in past approached this by doing local quorum and each quorum requests and comparing them. A problem of doing LQ then EQ writes is that when going to a remote DC, Cassandra will piggyback all the writes in that DC over a single proxy write (vs coordinator actually sending to each node). If that node hits a GC it is likely to get a spike. Also on modern clusters, there is speculative retry, which will still be adding the time of the first write to the latency.